# Android how to send image without chooser dialog in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-keypad

I have custom keyboard to share image to any application. Below code is running perfectly in Andron 4.4 and 5.1 but not working in 6.0 to share image.

```
    //get package name of current running application.
ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
packageName = mActivityManager.getRunningAppProcesses().get(1).processName;         

            //Sending  image to running application
            String s = arrPhoto.get(position).getImagName();
            File F = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/My Image/"+s);

            Uri U = Uri.fromFile(F);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            i.setType("image/png");
            i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, U);
            i.setPackage(packageName);
            startActivity(i);
```

Comment: What is the error, you are getting?

Comment: Hi Nigam,
When i run same thing in Android 6.0 then showing below error.

Process: com.keyboardsample, PID: 6620
                                                                  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
                                                                      at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)

Comment: May be you are lacking some permissions.

Comment: Hi Nigam,
Thank you so much for help me but kindly le me know about which permissions i have to use for such case.